# Can I wash my PCBs denatured alcohol

Tags: pcb-fabrication, cleaning

I have denatured alcohol which, according to wikipedia, is composed of roughly:

- 85% ethanol
- 10% water
- 3% methanol
- 1% aceton
- 1% pyridine

My solution has a blue color.
**Can I use this as a replacement for isoprop. or pure ethanol to clean my PCBs?**

Comment: It depends on if the residue that is left will affect your PCBs operation.

Comment: IPA should be obtainable (for private citizens) at or below $5 per liter at larger quantities, absolutely no more than $8 per liter bought per liter, or $10 ~ 15 per liter at sub-liter quantities. With 1 liter you should be able to clean dozens if not hundreds of square meters of PCB when used in the correct sparing manner. I think buying a small bottle of IPA isn't going to be the major cost of your hobby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acetone can dissolve some plastics, so I wouldn't use this unless it was carefully tested on those specific boards.

Comment: Do you maybe know if pyridine or the blue colorant can react with the pcb or leave residues which are conducting?